# How to create an array of integers in char type?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am trying to create an array of integers in char type for a given dimension. For instance if the dimension is 5 the array should be {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5'}, however I am not getting any output.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int dim = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    char [] num = new char[dim];
      for(int i = 49; i < dim; i++){
          for(int j = 0; j < dim; j++){
              num[j] = (char) i ;
          }
          System.out.println(num);
      }
}
```

Here I changed the code, I added an initial value ascii = 49:
But still I am not getting the desired output :(

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int dim = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    char [] num = new char[dim];
    int ascii = 49;
      for(int i = 0; i < dim; i++){
          for(int j = 0; j < dim; j++){
              num[j] = (char) (ascii + i) ;
          }
          System.out.println(num);
      }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you wrote what you wrote so that we not only can fix your code, but also tell you where the mistake is in your understanding?

Comment: I am trying to test if a given string is valid. The valid strings has to be in this form: A4, G6, B1... and so on. The first char of the string has to a capital letter and the second char has to be a number. I will include the rest of my code in the question. Thnx.

Comment: Hang on! Testing if a given string is valid has nothing to do with your original question of generating an array of chars `['1', '2', '3']`. Was your original question an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)?

Comment: Okay so the actual problem that I am trying to solve is to check if a given string is in a valid format. If the string is "abc" or "b56" it is false, the given string has to be a capital letter and a number (up to the given dimension).

Answer (score 2):

```
int dim = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

  for(int i = 49; i < dim; i++){
```

`dim` will need to be over 49 for the body of this loop to execute, and indeed there is output when you do so.

**Edit:** With the new code, the inner loop writes the same value over the entire array. The outer for loop does this for incrementing values, printing the array out each time.

Are you trying to do

```
          num[j] = (char) (ascii + j);
```

but perhaps without the outer for loop.

Comment: just out of curiosity, why are you starting the loop at 49? why not 1, and loop till `i <= dim`?

Comment: because the ascii value of char 1 is 49.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue might be here in the first for loop:

```
for(int i = 49; i < dim; i++){
```

The for loop will never be entered unless dim is greater than 49 (since you've specified i as 49 with the condition that dim must be greater than i [or i must be less than dim] for the loop to be executed.

If the first for loop is never entered, the print statement is never reached.

Comment: Oh right, I edited the question and added my new code :)

Comment: I looked at the comments below your post. Could you please update your question to specify exactly what you are trying to achieve. As the goal you state of outputting an array {'1','2','3','4','5'} (where the number of elements is specified by some input) needs only one for loop, yet you are using two.